# What does "that" in "outside that" refer to?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

Newt says about Obscurus:

> Newt: I managed to separate it from the Sudanese girl as I tried to save her.  So I wanted to take it home to study it. But it cannot survive outside **that**.

What does "that" refer to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [official screenplay](https://books.google.com/books?id=DU0LDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT123&lpg=PT123&dq=%22managed%20to%20separate%20it%20from%20the%20Sudanese%20girl%22%20as%20I%20tried%20to%20save%20her.%20So%20I%20wanted%20to%20take%20it%20home%20to%20study%20it.%20But%20it%20cannot%20survive&source=bl&ots=IoYnIQCOaK&sig=ACfU3U1-srKZpxXuM9u1GDfUwF8moc1n_w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMyc2bken2AhVUWs0KHVdBAuAQ6AF6BAglEAI#v=onepage&q=%22managed%20to%20separate%20it%20from%20the%20Sudanese%20girl%22%20as%20I%20tried%20to%20save%20her.%20So%20I%20wanted%20to%20take%20it%20home%20to%20study%20it.%20But%20it%20cannot%20survive&f=false), this is only part of the line:

> But it cannot survive outside that box, it could not hurt anyone, Tina!

The box that Newt is talking about is where he was storing the Obscurus.